# Can't Run Inference on TPU 3.8 VM TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

When I run the following with `tensorflow` in Kaggle with a TPU 3.8 VM accelerator:

```
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset.take(1))
```

I simply get the batch size in return; and if I run:

```
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset.take(2))
```

I get a list of two floats that are of batch size.

I think this is because the TPU nodes are reducing the probabilities and summing them. How can I actually get the predictions?

I initialized the TPUs with:

```
import tensorflow as tf

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

...and was able to train the model with them.

Any link to TPU inference code will help.

Comment: Please provide full reproducible code.